# keypress enter in jquery not firing after content change using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

i have jquery code to send request using ajax,.but after success function keypress not firing again this is my code

```
    $(".id_sort").bind('keypress',function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        var index_fix = [];
        var index_ori = [];
        for (i=0;i < $("tbody tr").length; i++){
            index_ori.push(i);
        }
        $(".id_sort").each(function(){
            index_fix.push(Number($(this).val())-1); 
        });
        if (JSON.stringify(index_fix) !== JSON.stringify(index_ori)){
            data = { key : 'sort', index : JSON.stringify(index_fix)};
            $.ajax({
                url : "/ajax/",
                data : data,
                type : "POST",
                cache : false,
                success : function (resp){
                        $(".data").html(resp);
                        // what should i do here..keypress enter doesn't work in second    time
                } 
            });     
        }
        else {
            alert("data sama coy");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser console for JavaScript errors. I suspect that maybe the JavaScript is throwing an error and not running this code anymore after the first keypress.

Is it a problem that if any of the fields of class .id_sort have anything in them besides blank that you'll get NaN when you convert to a number and when you pass the value to the server will it accept NaN for a value?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the dom node you're binding to may be getting replaced/overwritten by your `$(".data").html(resp);` call. Binding to events only work on nodes that are already in the dom.

So if that's the case, then you either need to rebind in your success callback after replacing the dom, or you can bind the click event to a higher node. For example: `$(".data").on("keypress", ".id_sort", function() { ... });`